# Symfony granting path access to multiple roles in security.yml

Tags: php, security, symfony, roles, access-control

Hi I would like to be able to allow access to a path in `security.yml` based on the user either having `ROLE_TEACHER`, or `ROLE_ADMIN`.

According to the question in [Multiple roles required for same url in symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798554/multiple-roles-required-for-same-url-in-symfony-2) the entry below should allow either role access.

```
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_TEACHER}
```

However, this will only allow the top role access.  Is there a way of having multiple role access to a single path?

Comment: Replacing order of entities still only results in one of the roles working.  Either of the two answers below allow usage of multiple roles.

Comment: Several entries with the same pattern would not work. First matching entry takes priority.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This is the way to go and what i'm using:

```
- { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TEACHER] }
```

Comment: if user has one or the other role it has access. you can combine it with the role hierarchy from @sergrkv answer and then a user has access to the rout if it has the role down the hierarchy chain

Comment: "Does this works in an OR logic?" Yes by default, but no if you use access_decision_manager.strategy: unaminous

Answer (score 18):

You can use the role hierarchy in `security.yml`:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_TEACHER]

#...

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_TEACHER}
```

So all of this roles will have access to that path.

Comment: If role1 inherits role2 then it will have access to all it's paths. If you want only 1 common path to be accessible for both roles and each have 5, then this example is not working.

Comment: @Udan the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles) says about hierarchy, and it works well in most cases when your application has a clean structure.

Comment: I didn't say it's wrong, just that it doesn't apply to all cases. The issue was about "having multiple role access to a single path" not to all paths the other role can access.

Comment: @Udan you are right about all cases. I think my answer like yours is not for all cases.